# Нужно подождать полной загрузки страницы и взять html

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Ничего дельного по этому поводу не нашел с использованием `Cefsharp.OffScreen`

Comment: Что такое полная загрузка страницы? Можно ли считать загрузку страницы оконченой если она загрузилась полностью но продолжают делатся аджакс запросы?

Comment: @Andrew Объясню по глупому, т.к терминов не знаю. Она загрузилась, когда кружочек перестал крутится

Answer (score 1):

Не могу сказать по поводу вашей конкретной библиотеки но могу подсказать путь как это можно реализовать технически:

Найдите на интересующей вас странице тэг внизу страницы который загружается одним из последних, и ориентируйтесь на него, грубо говоря начните загружать страницу и через интервал проверяйте появился ли искомый тег или нет, если не появился значит страница загрузилась не полностью.

Comment: Я догадывался на счет этого, но хотелось бы функцию, которая прям дождется полной загрузки страницы, но и этот ответ тоже подходит)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на второй мой вопрос, как получить Html.

```
 Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings(), performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);//Инициализация

 var Cefsh= new ChromiumWebBrowser();
  Cefsh.Load("https://...");
   Console.WriteLine(await Cefsh.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync());
//Получаем страницу /\
```

Ответ на второй вопрос, про ожидание полной загрузки страницы

```
 while (Cefsh.IsLoading)
  {
     Thread.Sleep (500);
     if (!Cefsh.IsLoading)
      {
      Console.WriteLine($"page loaded!");
      Console.WriteLine(await Cefsh.GetBrowser().MainFrame.GetSourceAsync());
      }
   }
```